# In Code Behind File, How to assign contentEditable="true" property to the TextBox?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox, contenteditable

I am binding some values to the TextBox using JavaScript. But During PostBack, the textbox values are cleared. So I used contentEditable="false" in the TextBox property.So the above problem get solved.

But, Suppose if there is no records to bind the TextBox using Javascript, at that time I want to set the textbox property contentEditable="true". So we can enter some values. How to do this in the Code Behind file?

This is my TextBox Sourcode:

This is my JavaScript to assign the Value to the TextBox:

```
function SuggessionSelectedValues(obj, ctrlName) 
    {
        if(ctrlName == "UCJobOrderNo")
        {             
            document.getElementById('<%=txtD1.ClientID %>').value         = obj[1];
        }
    }
```

I call this JavaScript function in One Dynamic Suggestion control.

Comment: Can you show us your code, so that we can give you a solution?

Comment: @Bibhu. I edited my Question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to give like this:

```
     txtD1.Attributes.Add("contentEditable", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

The TextBox control has an Attributes property, so in your code behind you could do:

```
MyTextBox.Attributes["contentEditable"] = recordCount == 0;
```

This would set the value of the contentEditable attribute based on the recordCount.

Comment: recordCount means? What it specifies? How to find recordCount?

Comment: that's just the number of records to bind.   In your question you say 'if there are no records to bind', so just declare an int called recordCount that is equal to the number of records.